# How to Change body parser limit in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions, body-parser

I'm trying to proxy a file upload to firebase cloud functions to not expose our API url.

Seems like Firebase is using Body-parser under the hood to parse body in the requests but it's limited to 100kb by default.

I've tried this:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));`

but it seems it's not using that bodyParser. It's using a private one embedded into Firebase's framework. Is there a way to change the limit on it?

This is what I'm getting:

> Blockquote 
>   error: { Error: request entity too large
>       at readStream (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:196:17)
>       at getRawBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:106:12)
>       at read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:76:3)
>       at urlencodedParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:115:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at textParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/text.js:78:7)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at rawParser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/raw.js:76:7)
>     expected: 611961,
>     length: 611961,
>     limit: 102400,
>     message: 'request entity too large',
>     status: 413,
>     statusCode: 413,
>     type: 'entity.too.large' }
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Do you also use: `app.use(express.json())`?
If you also use this middleware, express.json() has a limit of 100kb, you should try without it.